# drupal_http_request returns a XML as string

Tags: php, xml, drupal

I make a `drupal_http_request` to a server which sends me response data as the XML which is considered string in the Drupal server.

How do I parse this string as XML or convert this string into XML and then extract the information I am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Add the result inside a simpleXmlIterator object.

If the string is really a XML you'll be able to parse it.

As I just saw inside the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7)

You may do something like this

```
$obj = drupal_http_request($url);

$feed = new SimpleXmlIterator($obj->data);
```